# How to handle Express4 GET response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I might be doing something wrong : I want to set up a minimal API using NodeJS and Express4. Here I have this basic route in router.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({strict: true});

router.get('/beats', (request, response) => {
  response.status(200).json({'thisIs': 'a test'});
});
```

While in my front file main.js :

```
const beats = await fetch('/beats');
console.log(beats);
```

However, here is the response I receive in the frontend: 
[image: HTTTP Response]

As you can see, there is **no way to retrieve the JSON** I sent inside the router.js... 
Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Try `console.log(await beats.json());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A fetch methods works like this :*

**To get text response :**

```
fetch('myUrl').then(result => result.text()).then(text => console.log(text));
```

**To get json response :**

```
fetch('myUrl').then(result => result.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
```

**To not return a Promise:**

```
var myData = await fetch('myUrl').then(result => result.json()).then(json => json);
```

Comment: ok I see - I still get a Promise as the result, it nevers seems to be resolved

Comment: @FuméeNoire Just put an await before fetch